# MariaDB lacks a conf file?

Tags: mariadb

I have recently installed MariaDB on my server; however, it doesn't have the appropriate database settings for tweaking/tuning! Here is my "my.cnf":

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security   risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Where are the other settings?? Such as thread, memory adjustment, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Add what you need.  But generally you don't need any changes from the defaults *until* there is some kind of issue.